# Other Wagyu cuts beyond steaks

Tags: beef

I recently had the pleasure of a Wagyu sirloin steak and was blown away by the flavour and texture. At the cost it's not exactly the type of food you could have every week but what I wanted to know is are the cheaper cuts of Wagyu as different in flavour and texture as the prime cuts like sirloin and ribeye.

Is it worth trying to source Wagyu shin or brisket or are they similar to other good quality beefs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion the other cuts of Wagyu beef are equally more tasty than its domestic counterpart. So if you are comparing a USDA triple A piece of brisket with a Wagyu brisket the taste difference will be the same as the Wagyu sirloin compared to the USDA triple A sirloin. Whether it is worth the money or not is debatable, but if money is not an issue why not try sourcing the *cheaper* meats if such a description could be applied to a Wagyu beef cut.

I would consider the recipe you are planning to use these *cheaper* cuts for though; my point in this is if you are gettings shins for a stew are you really going to preserve the flavor of the meat enough to make it worth the price.

I could see smoking a nice Wagyu brisket though. If you decide to experiment I would love to hear your opinion.

I have had the sirloin, ribeye, and a brisket not smoked :/ and they have all been better comparatively to their domestic counterparts. I have not had all cuts of Wagyu beef, so my opinion is limited to what I have experienced.

Comment: Wow, the price for brisket is very low too. This isn't imported from Japan, but their prices for brisket are $5 / lbs, where as their tenderloin is $170 / lbs. That's a huge difference. The brisket isn't prized apparently... http://secure.abfoodsusa.com/category/catid/1/product-category-name/American-Style-Kobe-%2528Wagyu%2529-Beef.0

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm going to try and source some Wagyu brisket and shin and experiment with them. I see what you mean about losing the difference in flavour in a heavy stew but may try a simple ragu with limited other ingredients to see if I can get the beef flavour to shine through. Wagyu Ragu also has a nice sound to it!

Comment: Wagyu Ragu does sound good, let me know how your dish comes out!